# Order of the haggadah

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

Is there a logical order to the Haggadah, or is it just a collection of ideas/teachings relating to the exodus?

Comment: In a word - yes. It is designed to be structured in a way that is ordered ("seder") and most educationally compelling.

Comment: @Dov How do you know?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Bli neder I'll provide an answer tomorrow there are several I have seen in various haggados.

Comment: Moshechaim are you asking about the whole Seder procedure, or just the "maggid" section? Or just the story part of the maggid section "tzei ulmad"?

Comment: I'm mainly curious about the magid section. the stuff before "tzei ulmad" is there a sequence to those parts? and magid in general..